# Getting ValidationError when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource"

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

i am trying to deploy below stack using sam template where it supposed to deploy lambda and would add a s3 trigger, but iam getting following error

```
Getting ValidationError when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource"
```

i am not sure whats went wrong here to get such error

### yml template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
  S3:
    Type: String
  Key:
    Type: String
  SecretMgr:
    Type: String
  
Resources:
  LambdaS3ToKinesis:  
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 60
      FunctionName: !Sub "my_s3_to_kinesis" 
      CodeUri: ./test/src
      Role: !GetAtt testKinesisRole.Arn
      Description: "My lambda"
      Environment:
        Variables:
          KINESIS_STREAM: !Sub "test_post_kinesis"
          DDB_TRACKER_TABLE: my_tracker_table
          ENVIRONMENT: !Sub "${Environment}"
          BUCKET_NAME: !Sub "${S3}" 
      Events:
          FileUpload:
              Type: S3
              Properties:
                Bucket: !Sub "${S3}"
                Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
                Filter:
                  S3Key:
                    Rules:
                      - Name: prefix
                        Value: "${Environment}/test1/INPUT/"
                      - Name: suffix
                        Value: ".json"
                      - Name: prefix
                        Value: "${Environment}/test2/INPUT/"
                      - Name: suffix
                        Value: ".json"                     
                               
          


  LambdaTest1KinesisToDDB:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 60
      FunctionName: !Sub "${Environment}_test1_to_ddb"
      CodeUri: test1_kinesis_to_ddb/src/
      Role: !GetAtt testKinesisToDDBRole.Arn
      Description: "test post kinesis"
      Layers:
        - !Ref LambdaLayertest1
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: !Sub "${S3}"
          DDB_ACC_PLCY_TABLE:test1
          DDB_TRACKER_TABLE: test_tracker
          ENVIRONMENT: !Sub "${Environment}"
          S3_INVALID_FOLDER_PATH: invalid_payload/
          S3_RAW_FOLDER_PATH: raw_payload/
          S3_UPLOAD_FLAG: false
      Events:
        KinesisEvent:
          Type: Kinesis
          Properties:
            Stream: !GetAtt Kinesistest1.Arn
            StartingPosition: LATEST
            BatchSize: 1
            Enabled: true
            MaximumRetryAttempts: 0

  LambdaLayerTest1KinesisToDDB:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Sub "${Environment}_test1_kinesis_to_ddb_layer"
      ContentUri: test1_kinesis_to_ddb/dependencies/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.7

  testKinesisRole: 
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${Environment}_s3_to_kinesis_role"
      Description: Role for first lambda
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - s3.amazonaws.com   
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub "${Environment}_s3_to_kinesis_policy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:DeleteObject  
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${S3}/*" 
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${S3}"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kinesis:PutRecord
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:kinesis:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:mystream1/${Environment}_test1"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:kinesis:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:mystream2/${Environment}_test2"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:*
                  - cloudwatch:*
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - dynamodb:Put*
                  - dynamodb:Get*
                  - dynamodb:Update*
                  - dynamodb:Query
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt Dynamomytracker.Arn
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "${Key}"

  testKinesisToDDBRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${Environment}_test1_to_ddb_role"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - kinesis.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:test/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub "${Environment}_test1_kinesis_to_ddb_policy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:DeleteObject
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${S3}/*"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${S3}"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kinesis:Get*
                  - kinesis:List*
                  - kinesis:Describe*

                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt KinesisTest1.Arn
                  - !GetAtt KinesisTest2.Arn

              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - dynamodb:Put*
                  - dynamodb:Get*
                  - dynamodb:Describe*
                  - dynamodb:List*
                  - dynamodb:Update*
                  - dynamodb:Query
                  - dynamodb:DeleteItem
                  - dynamodb:BatchGetItem
                  - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
                  - dynamodb:Scan
                Resource:
                  - !Sub
                    - "${Table}*"
                    - { Table: !GetAtt "Dynamotest.Arn" }
                  - !Sub
                    - "${Table}*"
                    - { Table: !GetAtt "Dynamotest.Arn" }
                 
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "${Key}"

  ######################################
  # Update for TEst2
  ######################################
  KinesisTest2:
    Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}_test2_kinesis
      StreamEncryption:
        EncryptionType: KMS
        KeyId: !Sub "${Key}"
      RetentionPeriodHours: 24
      ShardCount: 1

  LambdaLayerTest2KinesisToDDB:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: !Sub "${Environment}_test2_kinesis_to_ddb_layer"
      ContentUri: test2_kinesis_to_ddb/dependencies/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: python3.7

  LambdaTest2KinesisToDDB:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Timeout: 60
      FunctionName: !Sub "${Environment}_Test2_kinesis_to_ddb"
      CodeUri: Test2_kinesis_to_ddb/src/
      Role: !GetAtt testKinesisToDDBRole.Arn
      Description: "Test2"
      Layers:
        - !Ref LambdaLayerTest2KinesisToDDB
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: !Sub "${S3}"
          DDB_ACC_PLCY_TABLE: my_table2
          DDB_TRACKER_TABLE: my_log
          ENVIRONMENT: !Sub "${Environment}"
          S3_INVALID_FOLDER_PATH: invalid_payload/
          S3_RAW_FOLDER_PATH: raw_payload/
          S3_UPLOAD_FLAG: false
      Events:
        KinesisEvent:
          Type: Kinesis
          Properties:
            Stream: !GetAtt KinesisTest2.Arn
            StartingPosition: LATEST
            BatchSize: 1
            Enabled: true
            MaximumRetryAttempts: 0
```

can anybody help me how can resolve this? i am not sure what exactly missed in the template and how to resolve this error

Comment: You have several GetAtt. Which resource it fails for?

Comment: You're referencing both `KinesisTest1` and `Kinesistest1` which don't exist. Next time look at each usage of `GetAtt` and see if the resource name you've specified actually exists. And remember it's case sensitive.

Comment: yes @Marcin i added missed reference and that issue resolved, but now i am getting below error
"Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::Serverless::Function, AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion] (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;"

Comment: I see you posted a new question with added `Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31` as I wrote. Thus I would appreciate accepting my answer as it helped you pass the error you reported in this question.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you get that error?

Comment: yes @Marcin i didnt get

Comment: How come? In your next question you are already using code which includes my answer `Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31`? This means that you are passed the errors reported in this question, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

You are using [AWS Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html) and your template does not conform to its [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html). For example, its missing **required**  `Transform` statement:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
```

There could be many other things wrong, as your template is nor CloudFormation nor Serverless at this point.